# Why when I make "var" and make it equals to document.getElementById it doesn't works?

Tags: javascript, variables

Ok so the thing that I am asking is in the Tilte. I have that code:

```
function fromPassToText(inputId) {
        var theThing = document.getElementById(inputId).type;
        if (theThing  == "password")
            theThing  = "text";
        else
            theThing  = "password";
    }
```

And it is not going in the if. When I rename all of `theThing` with `document.getElementById(inputId).type` its allright.

I am new and I will apreciate it if you help me.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to include relative markup and function calls here. It is hard to tell what is not working from how you've written your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure, that your code is "going into the if statement".

I guess, you are wondering, why the type did not change. It did not, because you change only the variable.

What you want to do is:

```
function fromPassToText(inputId) {
    var theThing = document.getElementById(inputId);
    if (theThing.type  == "password")
        theThing.type  = "text";
    else
        theThing.type  = "password";
}
```

This way you change the element and not only the variable.

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
theThing  = "text";
```

or

```
theThing  = "password";
```

you are only changing the local variable. I assume you need to change the DOM element's property and the only way to do that would be by using `document.getElementById(inputId).type =`

---

By the way, this would work too

```
function fromPassToText(inputId) {
    var theThing = document.getElementById(inputId).type;
    if (theThing  == "password")
        document.getElementById(inputId).type = "text";
    else
        document.getElementById(inputId).type = "password";
}
```

Comment: It would be better to do `var theInput = document.getElementById(inputId); if(theInput.type == "password") theInput.type = "text"; else theInput.type = "password";` - although it should be noted that some browsers don't support changing the type of an input once it's on the page, and others provide this functionality as standard. Curiously, "Internet Explorer" is the browser I'm thinking of in both cases...

Comment: Oww yeah. I get it. Thanks potatopeelings and Niet the Dark Absol, you really helped me understanding that! :) Have a nice day

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol  - yep, that is definitely clearer, but *theThing* will make folks think twice before changing this bit of code :-)

Comment: @BG-DiscoX - you would be better off hiding / showing a text / password control instead of changing the control type. Thanks Niet the Dark Absol!

Comment: @potatopeelings - I am doing that because you hit a button and you can see your password if you want to check if it is as it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

The answers so far are only *partially* right.

They are correct that this will not work:

```
var theThing = document.getElementById(inputId).type;
theThing  = "text";
```

This is because you are getting a primitive type value (a string) and  Javascript passes those around by value.

However, this *would* work:

```
var theInput = document.getElementById(inputId);
theInput.type  = "text";
```

This is because you are setting `theInput` to an object, and objects are passed around by reference. So, for all intents and purposes, `theInput` is the element itself.